# How to remove white spaces on highcharts chart in R

Tags: r, highcharts, r-highcharter

This is my data:

```
 df_cards <- structure(list(x = c("Jan - 2021", "Feb - 2021", "Mar - 2021", 
"Apr - 2021", "May - 2021"), y = c(22.7851010020822, 24.7339859977365, 
27.2432568809018, 29.1082223854028, 29.049789654091), colors = c("#0F60D2", 
"#0F60D2", "#EF2D3E", "#EF2D3E", "#EF2D3E")), class = "data.frame", row.names = c("color1", 
"color2", "color3", "color4", "color5"))
```

This is the chart code:

```
hchart(
  df_cards,
  "area",
  hcaes(x, y, color = colors),

  name = "Revenue",
  color = sample_2_colors,
  showInLegend = TRUE
)
```

This is the plot:
[image]

How can I remove the white spaces that I pointed on the chart on the left and on the right?

Answer (score 2, accepted):

To fix your issue convert your dates to proper dates and set your desired format for the axis labels via `hc_xAxis`:

```
library(highcharter)

df_cards$x <- as.Date(paste("2021", 1:5, 1, sep = "-"))

hchart(
  df_cards,
  "area",
  hcaes(x, y, color = colors),
  name = "Revenue",
  showInLegend = TRUE
) |>
  hc_xAxis(labels = list(format = "{value:%b - %Y}"))
```

[image]